# Differentiate $(x-1)^2 \sin x$ where $x$ is in radians

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

How would I differentiate, simplify and then find $f'(\pi/2)$:

$$
f(x)=(x-1)^2 \sin x
$$

I'm not sure how to differentiate $\sin x$ to then use it later to find an answer, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $(\sin x)'=\cos x$

Comment: $dsinx/dx=cosx$, and now just apply the product rule for derivatives, e.g.: $f(x)=g(x)r(x)$; $f'(x)=g'(x)r(x)+g(x)r'(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*:

- Use the product rule and the chain rule to find $f'(x)$.
- Plug in $x=\pi/2$ and evaluate the expression.

---

*Solution*:

$f'(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}(x-1)^2\cdot\sin x+\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin x \cdot (x-1)^2=2(x-1)\cdot\sin x + (x-1)^2\cdot\cos x$

$f'(\pi/2)=2(\pi/2-1)\cdot\sin \pi/2 + (\pi/2-1)^2\cdot\cos \pi/2=\pi-2$

Comment: I have tried using the product rule and have gotten $(x-1)(2*sin(pi/180*x) + (x-1)(pi/180)cosx)$ but when I put pi/2 into this I do not get the answer of $pi-2$ as stated in the book

Comment: I think you are not applying the product rule right. You should not get any $\pi/180$..

Comment: @Rainer Yeah it seems that way, There was something in a previous exercise that said about converting to radians first

Comment: Glad I could help. :)